# How to materialize the group key for each row of the original dataframe? ('by' is a pandas grouper)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to materialize for each row of a dataframe the corresponding group key it would get if I was using a `groupby` operation with a pandas `Grouper`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Test data
ts = [pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 09:00'),
      pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 10:00'),
      pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 10:30'),
      pd.Timestamp('2022/03/01 15:00')]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(len(ts)), 'ts': ts})

grouper = pd.Grouper(key='ts', freq='2H', sort=False, origin='start_day')
```

Is there any way to get for each row the corresponding groupkey?
The result I am looking for could be either a list, or a pandas Series or Index, or numpy array, the same length as the initial dataframe, and would then contain following values.

```py
result = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2022-03-01 08:00:00'),
                    pd.Timestamp('2022-03-01 10:00:00'),
                    pd.Timestamp('2022-03-01 10:00:00'),
                    pd.Timestamp('2022-03-01 14:00:00')])
```

Thanks for your help!
Bests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly using the `groupby` but you can use:

```
df['ts'].dt.floor('2H')
```

With the `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(grouper)['ts'].transform(lambda g: g.name)
```

Output:

```
0   2022-03-01 08:00:00
1   2022-03-01 10:00:00
2   2022-03-01 10:00:00
3   2022-03-01 14:00:00
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar idea to @Andrej, just creates a table with a new column

```
pd.concat(g.assign(grouper_val = i) for i,g in df.groupby(grouper))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
   a                  ts
0  0 2022-03-01 09:00:00
1  1 2022-03-01 10:00:00
2  2 2022-03-01 10:30:00
3  3 2022-03-01 15:00:00
```

Doing:

```
pd.Series(df.resample('2H', origin='start_day', on='ts').groups)
```

Output:

```
2022-03-01 08:00:00    1
2022-03-01 10:00:00    3
2022-03-01 12:00:00    3
2022-03-01 14:00:00    4
dtype: int64
```